# How to ensure block elements will be on same line in a table?

Tags: html, css

I have a `<table>` where the last column contains some action `<button>`s. The other columns contain paragraphs of text. Because they contain text, their width extends as much as possible and then the text wraps. That is fine for all columns but the last. I don't want the buttons in the actions column to wrap; I want them on a single line. How to can I do that?

See [this](http://jsfiddle.net/YJyan/2/) jsfiddle for a demo the the problem.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's as simple as this:

```css
.actions {
    /* EDIT: float is not necessary in table cells – float: left; */
    white-space: nowrap;
}
```

#### Demo (forked fiddle)

http://jsfiddle.net/insertusernamehere/XUda2/

Comment: Yeah it should work without. I left in inside because I wasn't shure for what reason you have added it. Actually float should have no effect on table rows and cells.

Answer (score 3):

The key is to use `nowrap`.

```
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>Text</td>
    <td>Text</td>
    <td>Text</td>
    <td nowrap="nowrap"><button>Button</button></td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: What? do you mean `<td style="whitespace: nowrap">`?

Comment: The `nowrap` attribute is simpler, and it works even when CSS is disabled. And there are fewer chances of typos, like `whitespace` for `white-space`. :-) But many people frown upon presentational HTML attributes.